# Unable to delete 3rd vertex of a polygon | OpenLayers6

Tags: openlayers

When polygon has 3 vertices left I am unable to delete any of those vertices:

```
var modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
   features: selectCtrl.getFeatures(),
   deleteCondition: function(event) {  
       return keys['46']; // 46 = delete key
   }
});
```

Comment: Why is this surprising? Polygons ***require*** three discrete vertices.

Comment: I would expect that deleting 3rd vertice of a polygon would remove entire polygon. That is what I want - a polygon to be deleted when attempt to delete 3rd vertice of the polygon is made. This is not built-in?

Comment: Because it seems to me it worked this way on OpenLayers2

Comment: In the current version there must be at least 4 coordinates (including one to close the ring) before you can delete https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/src/ol/interaction/Modify.js#L1143

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up modifying `ol.interaction.Modify.removeVertex_` to track which features were being attempted to be modified. By that I mean when the flow would go to `else` block https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/src/ol/interaction/Modify.js#L1143 I would register `segmentData.feature` as a feature that was supposed to be deleted and handle the "delete feature" logic in overridden version of `ol.interaction.Modify.removePoint` where the deletion would happen after calling the original `ol.interaction.Modify.removePoint`